# how allocate attribute for each sensor node in ant colony clustering WSN?

Tags: ant-colony

I am working on particle swarm ant colony system for WSN clustering in sensor network node i gave every sensor node  x and y coordinate

I dont know, how to assign each sensor node attribute according to equation for calculation centers for nodes ,can anybody help me please .

Comment: You should probably ask something more specific.

Comment: how i can add attribute to each node have x and y coordinate i tried to upload the equation but not allowed to me